# Spring reactor join 2 Mono

Tags: spring-boot, project-reactor, reactor

I need to connect to database in reactive way using spring reactor.
Here is scenario which I would like to get->

1. 1.Connect to db and get response1

   2.Then Connect to db and get response2 while providing response1.parameter

   3. Join those two into single response and send back to the user as String

Since all objects are unique I planned to use Mono

```
Mono<Response1> r1 = qrepo.findByID(id)
Mono<Response2> r2 = qrepo.findByID(r1.getParam())

Mono<String> combined = Mono.when(r1, r2).map(t -> { 
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                sb.append(r1.getProp1());
                sb.append(r2.getProp2());
```

But this  doesn't wor for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should get response1 then flatMap its result to access parameter and pass it to repository then map result to string

```
    Mono<String> resultMono = qrepo.findByID(id)
            .flatMap(response1 -> qrepo.findByID(response1.getParam())
                    .map(response2 -> {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.append(response1.getProp1());
                        sb.append(response2.getProp2());
                        return sb.toString();
                    }));
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use Mono.zip**

Example:

```
Mono.zip(Mono.just("hello"), Mono.just("world")).map(tuple2 -> {

      return tuple2.getT1() + tuple2.getT2();
    });
```

Mono.zip aggregate given monos into a new Mono that will be fulfilled when all of the given Monos have produced an item.

Comment: This is not the answer to the OP, but it's the answer I was looking for :-)

Comment: `.getT1()` and `.getT2()` finalises await and results get collected. If this to be joined. then maybe use `flatMap()` to generate another mono of their combination